# Ahlfors' method of calculating the fundamental group of a punctured disk

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text, page 297 he determines the fundamental group of the punctured disk $\{0<|z|<\rho \}$. His approach is to divide any loop $\gamma$ into short enough arcs, by the intermediate points $P_1,P_2, \dots P_n$ as well as $P_0=r<\rho$ and $P_0'=-r$. During the proof he writes:

> As a result $\gamma$ can be deformed into a product of simple arcs with the successive end points $P_0P_1P_2 \cdots P_nP_0.$ This path may in turn be replaced
>   by $P_0P_1P_2P_0P_2P_3P_0 \cdots P_0P_{n-l}P_nP_0$ *where each arc $P_kP_0$ and $P_0P_k$ is, for definiteness, the one which does not contain $P_0'$* In fact, the new path is obtained by inserting the doubly traced arcs $P_kP_0P_k$ which we know to be homotopic to $1$.

I have two small questions regarding this

1. Why isn't there ambiguity? If one of the $P_k$ is $P_0'=-r$ both arcs $P_kP_0$ contain $P_0'$.
2. When he says homotopic to $1$, he means homoptic to the constant curve based at $P_k$, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1.: Ambiguity doesn't hurt, as long as you use the same arc to go from $P_k$ to $P_0$ and back, the homotopy class is not changed. You can add the rule "if $P_k = P_0'$, then choose the upper [or lower, if you prefer] arc" to disambiguate, or demand that the subdivision is made such that none of the $P_k$ is $P_0'$. It should have been mentioned that $P_k = P_0'$ is to be avoided or handled specially.

In view of the next paragraph, that, as [Post No Bills](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111742/post-no-bills) [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621440/ahlfors-method-of-calculating-the-fundamental-group-of-a-punctured-disk/621467#comment1309285_621467) (thanks), says that if $P_kP_{k+1}$ contains $P_0'$, then the curve $P_0P_kP_{k+1}P_0$ is homotopic to either $C$ or $C^{-1}$, the resolution should be to avoid $P_0'$ as a subdivision point (otherwise, $P_0P_kP_{k+1}P_0$ might also be nullhomotopic).

Ad 2.: Exactly. Homotopic to $1$ means homotopic to a constant loop [$1$ is the neutral element of a group, in this case the fundamental group of the circle with base point $P_k$, although it serves to get a subdivision into loops based at $P_0$]. In words, one says "nullhomotopic", and one often also sees $\gamma \sim 0$ to indicate that.

Comment: One more remark: in the following paragraph, Ahlfors says: if $P_{k}P_{k+1}$ contains $P_0'$, the curve $P_0P_kP_{k+1}P_0$ is homotopic to $C$ or $-C$, where $C$ is the full circle. This is not necessarily true if $P_k$ or $P_{k+1}$ is $P_0'$, since our choices of semi-circle can make $P_0P_kP_{k+1}P_0$ null homotopic. Not that it matters at the end, since the desired conclusion is that $\gamma$ is some power of $C$.